# Task 'check' not found in root project

Tags: java, debugging, gradle

I am trying to run my gradle project in debug mode but it is giving the error: Task 'check' not found in root project.Here is a snippet of error stack:

```
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'check' not found in root project 'payment_dashboard'.
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.getSelection(DefaultTaskSelector.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.getFilter(DefaultTaskSelector.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.CompositeAwareTaskSelector.getFilter(CompositeAwareTaskSelector.java:55)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
```

### How can I skip the task or if possible I can run my gradle successfully. I tried gradle tasks and the output shows:
Verification tasks

check - Runs all checks.

As a resolution, I tried gradle clean and gradle build, but in build it was showing errors in test but I skipped those using exclude in the build.gradle .

Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip this check , you can try `gradle build -x check --debug` , this will build without calling the check task . but i do not recommend this as with the name 'check' is missing , you ll probably hit with bigger issues sooner or later .

Comment: This happens when I click on the debug button in intellij. The edit configuration has command clean build --exclude-task check --stacktrace but this throws the error:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'check' not found in root project.
Please help as I need to debug the project urgently.